# How to stretch the DIV based on the contents

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a div which has some contents and the HTML is as follow:

```
<div id="subpageFooter">
    <div id="subpageFooterLeft">
        <div style="z-index: 15; position: relative; left: 0; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 30px; font-weight: bold; color: #00A0BE; font-size: 13px;">
            State-Of-The-Art-Technology
        </div>
        <div style="z-index: 14; position: relative; left: 0; padding-left: 40px; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 8px; font-weight: normal; color: #000000; font-size: 12px;">
            Our state-of-the-art technology ensures that we provide the finest healthcare. Our practice continuously invests in systems and equipment so that physicians can diagnose problems in the most accurate and efficient manner possible.
        </div>
        <div style="position: relative; width: 90%; padding-left: 5%; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 5%;"><hr /></div>
        <div style="z-index: 13; position: relative; left: 0; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 10px; font-weight: bold; color: #00A0BE; font-size: 13px;">
            Advanced Electronic Medical Records
        </div>
        <div style="z-index: 12; position: relative; left: 0; padding-left: 40px; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 8px; font-weight: normal; color: #000000; font-size: 12px;">
            Our advanced electronic medical record improves patient care and gives physicians all of the important patient information they need in one place.
        </div>
        <div style="position: relative; width: 90%; padding-left: 5%; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 5%;"><hr /></div>
        <div style="z-index: 11; position: relative; left: 0; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 10px; font-weight: bold; color: #00A0BE; font-size: 13px;">
            Premier Radiology Services
        </div>
        <div style="z-index: 10; position: relative; left: 0; padding-left: 40px; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 8px; font-weight: normal; color: #000000;font-size: 12px;">
            Filmless radiology capabilities provide rapid results and allow physicians to view images on an office computer screen within minutes. Our premier radiology services include MRI, CT scan, ultrasonography, nuclear medicine, bone densitometry and mammography. We offer computer-aided diagnosis (CAD), which is a tool to assist the radiologist in more accurately diagnosing breast disease.
        </div>
        <div style="position: relative; width: 90%; padding-left: 5%; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 5%;"><hr /></div>
        <div style="z-index: 9; position: relative; left: 0; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 10px; font-weight: bold; color: #00A0BE; font-size: 13px;">
            Our Employees Make MED a Special Place
        </div>
        <div style="z-index: 8; position: relative; left: 0; padding-left: 40px; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 8px; font-weight: normal; color: #000000; font-size: 12px;">
            MED values each of our employees’ experience, diversity and dedication. Ideas and backgrounds that our employees bring to our company enable us to be more effective in anticipating and exceeding our patients’ needs and expectations. <a class="blueLinks" href="http://www.MEDgroup.com/talented_people.aspx">Click here</a> for the opportunity to meet some of the employees who greatly contribute to our success.
        </div>
        <div style="position: relative; width: 90%; padding-left: 5%; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 5%;"><hr /></div>
        <div style="z-index: 7; position: relative; left: 0; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 10px; font-weight: bold; color: #00A0BE; font-size: 13px;">
            Wide Range Of Insurances
        </div>
        <div style="z-index: 6; position: relative; left: 0; padding-left: 40px; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 8px; font-weight: normal; color: #000000; font-size: 12px;">
            A big advantage to using MED Medical Group is the <a class="blueLinks" href="http://www.MEDgroup.com/participating_insurance.aspx?id=473">wide range of insurance coverage</a> accepted. This means you should be able to keep your doctors even if you find you have to change insurance plans. We care equally about every patient regardless of the insurance provider.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="subpageFooterRight">
        <!-- #include virtual ="includeNav/hospAff.inc" -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is this:

```
#subpageFooter {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 715px;
    background: url('../theImages/bg_90_w.png');
    /*box-shadow: 0 0 10px #FFFFFF;*/
}
#subpageFooterRight {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    background: url('../theImages/vshadow.png') 0 0 repeat-y;
    text-align: center;
}
#subpageFooterLeft {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

When I zoom in, the contents goes out of the `subpageFooterLeft` div

[image]

How can I modify it so the div stretches to match the contents?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the css:

```
height: auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're setting `height: 100%` to #subpageFooterLeft. Removing this rule fixes the zooming issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/qtDm3/

```
#subpageFooterLeft {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    /* height: 100%; */
}
```

Comment: I think what is causing the issue is I am using Media Queries and depending on the screen size changing the stylesheet. How can I make sure if it's desktop none of the non-desktop styles kicks in?

Comment: Not certain what you mean by "desktop none." Is it possible you still have `height: 100%` or another height value assigned in one of your media queries?

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting this in the css also:

`overflow:auto;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
overflow:hidden;
height:1%;
```

Comment: where should I add that?